# Determine commits on a branch not on another

Tags: git, branching-and-merging

I have a topic branch that I've been working on for quite some time and I would like to see just the changes made to this branch. For awhile I was being good and merging the master branch into my topic branch periodically, but eventually I forgot and now it's diverged tremendously.

For example, let's say I have a history like:

```
         q---r---s---t---u---v---w---x---y---z---my_topic
        /           /           /
---a---b---c---d---e---f---g---h---i---j---k---l---m---HEAD
            \         /
             1---2---3   (another topic)
```

In this case, I would like to just see commits r, s, u, v, x, y, z for example. I don't want to see any changes introduced by the merges. But since the branch diverged from HEAD, I can't just look at the difference between HEAD and my branch. And they diverged to the point that merging them together is a heck of a lot of work just to see the differences.

So is there a way to see the commits made on a given branch that did not originate on another branch or as a result of a merge with another branch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can display the commits that are in `my_topic` but not in `HEAD`, excluding merge commits using:

```
git log --no-merges HEAD..my_topic
```

You could actually leave `HEAD` out and just use `..my_topic`, but the two commitish form is more general.

Comment: This works, but just in case it's not clear, this command should be run on the main branch, not `my_topic`.

Comment: That's correct. If you want to run it from the main branch, you could use the name of that branch in place of `HEAD`.